# How to put different dataframes in different sheets using xlwings,python?

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, loops, xlwings

How can I loop over worksheets to put different dataframes using xlwings python?
I have three different dataframes that I want to put them in A1 cell of three different sheet.
I tried the following code-ish lines and got this error.

com_error: (-2147352567, '例外が発生しました。', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147352565), None)

```
wb = xw.Book()
sheetnames = ["daily", "monthly", "yearly"]
dfLists = [df1,df2,df3]
for i in [sht for sht in sheetnames]:
    for j in dfLists:
        wb.sheets[i].range('A1').value = dfLists[j]
```

Comment: Can you please specify your question more precisely? Do you want to use `print()` on all of your worksheets? Or do you want to set the values of cells in worksheets?

Comment: @mouwsy I want to set 3 different dataframes in 3 different sheets.

Comment: Which dataframes? Pandas dataframes?

Comment: @mouwsy yes, pandas datafram. Or any table, ust different data on different page

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy excel worksheets to another workbook use:

```
import xlwings as xw

path_from = r"C:\Users\user_name\Desktop\asdf.xlsx"
path_to = r"C:\Users\user_name\base_book.xlsx"

sheetnames = ["daily", "monthly", "weekly"]

with xw.App(visible=False) as app:
    wb_from = xw.Book(path_from)
    wb_to = xw.Book(path_to)

    for sheetname in sheetnames:
        ws_to_copy = wb_from.sheets[sheetname]
        ws_to_copy.api.Copy(Before=None, After=wb_to.sheets[-1].api)
    wb_to.save()
    wb_to.close()
```

If you want to copy pandas dataframes to your workbook use:

```
import xlwings as xw
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd._testing.makeDataFrame()
df2 = pd._testing.makeDataFrame()
df3 = pd._testing.makeDataFrame()

sheetnames = ["daily", "monthly", "weekly"]
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]

with xw.App(visible=False) as app:
    wb = xw.Book()
    for sheetname, df in zip(sheetnames, dfs):
        wb.sheets.add(name=sheetname)
        wb.sheets[sheetname].range("A1").value = df
    wb.save()
    wb.close()
```

You could also use [xlsxwriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html#ewx-pandas) if you want to export pandas dataframes to excel.